# Python 3.6 If Statement with Criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

I am trying to create a classic if statement with criteria in Python 3. I am able to input a number from this code, but am not able to figure out why the code will not print "hot" or "cold". What can I do to fix this? Do I need to have an `elif` with this statement?

```
N = float(input(("Enter Number: ")))
def is_hot (N):
    if N/2>1 and N-1>1:
        print (N, "is hot")
    else:
        N/2<1 and N-1<1
        print (N, "is cold")
```

Comment: Can you format this into a code block? Reading that in plaintext is kind of painful.

Comment: Looks like you need an `elif` rather than `else`

Comment: yup its not formatted correctly one but else won't let you have a conditional statement in it itll just error out @BradSolomon said it right

Comment: What about when N is 2? Is that "hot", "cold", or "just right"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your function, because it looks like it needs an `elif ...:` instead of an `else:`  And you need to actually invoke the function, too, once you've gotten your input. So...

```
def is_hot (N):
    if N/2>1 and N-1>1:      # N > 2
        print (N, "is hot")
    elif N/2<1 and N-1<1:    # N < 2
        print (N, "is cold")
    else:                    # N is 2
        print (N, "is just right!")
n = float(input(("Enter Number: ")))
is_hot(n)
```

Note that I did not use *N* in both places, when calling the func and when defining the func. It would work, but it's not always the best thing as far as code readability.

Also, it's best practice to list your functions at the top of your code.

Also, you can, and probably should, use a different variable names in the function than in the calling code. This is not for functionality, but for readability. If someone is not paying attention, they may see the same name and think it's a global variable. Again, you do not have to use a different variable name, but it's good practice to use different variable names. If nothing else, the variable names in the function will often be more generic, and the variable names in the calling code more specific.  Here's an example:

```
def merge_lists(list1, list2): # generic..
    return zip(list1, list2)
my_merged_inventory_list = merge_lists(list_of_stock_items, list_of_item_prices)
```

Comment: What happens if N/2 is 1? Is it really a case of on or off?  Maybe you need a final `else:` statement that says "is just right". If N is 2, is that hot, cold, or just right?

Comment: Thank you all for your help! This worked perfectly. Why should N not be used in both places? What would the logic be there?

When you call the function, you can use a different variable?

Comment: Yes, you can, and probably should, use a different variable name. Not for functionality, but for readability. If someone is not paying attention, they may seem the same name and think it's a global variable. Again, you do not have to use a different variable name, but it's good practice to use different variable names. If nothing else, the variable names in the function will often be more generic, and the variable names in the calling code more specific.

Answer (score 3):

As @Brad Solomon mention in the comments. Instead of else you shoud use elif.

```
N = float(input(("Enter Number: ")))
def is_hot (N):
    if (N/2>1 and N-1>1):
        print (N, "is hot")
    elif (N/2<1 and N-1<1) :
        print (N, "is cold")
    else :
        print(N,"neither hot nor cold")

is_hot(N)
```

**Note** :- you can also add a default condition (`else` part) where it doesn't match either of the cases.
**Update** :- Added the calling of the function as suggested by Gary

Answer (score 3):

Because you only defined the function `is_hot(N)`, but you didn't call it.

Comment: Rereading the question, I think this is actually what @Danielle is asking.  Call `is_hot(N)` after your function, or remove the if statement from the function.